# How to set up the Partition-level notifications and subscribe to them?

Tags: here-olp

I've been trying to set up the Partition-level notifications for a catalog and I found it's not as straightforward as the Catalog-level notifications, does anyone have an example or something I could use as an starting point ?

I've been reading the OLP documentation but it's still wide confusing, and I haven't found a sample Java/Scala code.

I expect to set Partition-level notifications for a catalog and consume them using Java/Scala.